# Using laravel to convert videos with AWS Amazon Elastic Transcoder

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, ffmpeg-php, amazon-elastic-transcoder

Just wanted to know if it's possible to use laravel with Amazon Elastic Transcoder. having a lot of issues using FFMPEG to convert videos as it's always timing out on larger video files event though I have set the timeout to 60000.

Is there a plugin of some sort for laravel that will assist in using AWS Elatic Transcoder.

Thanks in advance
Danny